# galactic keepout_filter inflation

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ros2 galactic installed from ros-testing repository

I implemented the keepout_filter as described in the official doc, the problem is that the forbidden areas are not inflated which results that the robot cannot avoid them. as seen in the image below.

**I am wondering how can I set the inflation to danger areas as shown in stevemacenski's [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZnkLtdv3BU). Thanks in advance**

[image: image description]

**Then:**

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379671/galactic-keepout_filter-inflation/) by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Costmap filters are no longer applied with the inflation layer. As the keepout / speed zones are meant to place a mask on specific no-go or high cost areas, it didn’t make sense for us to inflate them since they themselves should be representative of the areas the robot should not enter.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2021-06-06**:
Thanks for the answer.
without inflation (for keepout zones only), the robot is not be able to follow the path generated by global plan as shown in the image. I tried to set the filter to global costmap only and delete it for local costmap but the robot still can't reach the goal.